# Use name of #define parameter without stringification

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

Is there a way to get the exact words passed into the `#define` without stringifying? Example use case:

```
#define NUM 1

#define CREATE_FUN(X) \
void prefix_X() { \ // used exact words passed in
    int x = X; \ // use value later on
}

CREATE_FUN(NUM)
```

And output would look like:

```
void prefix_NUM() {
    int x = 1;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the token concatenation (`##`):

```
#define NUM 1

#define CREATE_FUN(X) \
void prefix_##X() { \
    int x = X; \
}

CREATE_FUN(NUM)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#define CREATE_FUN(X) \
int prefix_##X() { \
    int x = X; \
    return x; \
}

CREATE_FUN(NUM)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Token Pasting(##) operator:

```
#define CREATE_FUN(X) int prefix_##X() { int x=X; return x;}
```

Sample use case:

> Some compilers provide an extension that allows `##` to appear after a comma and before `__VA_ARGS__`, in which case
>
> 1. the `##` does nothing when **VA_ARGS** is non-empty
> 2. removes the comma when **VA_ARGS** is empty.

This makes it possible to define macros with variable number of arguments such as `fprintf (stderr, format, ##__VA_ARGS__)`